# Will macro-ing the space bar mess up its command navigation?

Tags: key-bindings

I am considering attaching a macro to the space bar to insert a space.

My question is whether this will change its normal mode behavior. For example, if I type `23<space>` will it execute the macro 23 times or do the normal thing (move forward 23 spaces)?

I want to keep the old functionality for repetitive actions because the space navigation goes past end of line but 'L' navigation does not.

Just to clarify, this is the behavior I am envisioning:

- typing "400< space bar >" moves forward 400 characters including past end of line
- hitting the  bar inserts one space in normal mode, ie:

  ```
  :nnoremap <space> i<space><esc>
  ```

Not sure if it possible to achieve both these objectives. If it is not possible, then maybe the best option is to change the normal space bar behavior to a different key, since I very rarely use the space bar for navigation. Maybe Shift+Spacebar for movement?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "attaching a macro to the space bar". A macro can be recorded in the registers `{0-9a-zA-Z"}` not in `space`. To change the behavior of the space bar in insert mode you can remap it with `inoremap <Space> [...]` is that what you are talking about? If so the answer is `inoremap` will change the behavior of the space bar only in insert mode, while `nnoremap` will change the behavior in normal mode.

Comment: @statox Yes, that is what I am talking about, but I would want the mapping to work in command mode, so maybe it is not feasible without breaking the normal functionality.

Comment: When you say you want the mapping to work in command mode, you mean when typing `:echo` (or any other command) and then pressing `Space` you want the space bar to do something else than inserting only one space?

Comment: @statox I meant normal mode, I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok it's more clear now. I think you can't get two different behaviors in the same mode. But a simple solution would be to use another mapping like `< C-Space>` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Using a function, you can split the functionality of a key map. In this case, the determining factor is if a count is given to the command or not, which is stored in `v:count`.

```
function! SpaceOrSpace(cnt)
  if a:cnt > 0
    exec "normal " . a:cnt . "l"
  else
    normal i ^[
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Space> :<C-U>call SpaceOrSpace(v:count)<CR>
```

**Note** the `^[` character in the script is created by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

The function is pretty simple. If the count is greater than zero move the cursor right as many times. Otherwise insert a space and return to normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that a macro on space would become an annoyance very quickly. (assuming a macro is external to vi bindings) I had tried something like that with a `fn+key` on my keyboard and found that it could be solved with some `vimL`

From the question it sounds like you are looking for a way to navigate in `normal` (having cursor wrap lines). I'd recommend staying within vim to accomplish your goal.

The first thing I would look at is other events that are triggered when you navigate to the end of the line using `hjkl`. On my config I hear the annoying bell which leads me to think there must be some event associated with cursor movement (assuming knowledge of `autocmds`). After running `:help autocmd-events` I stumbled on the following

> ```
>           CursorMoved
> ```
>
> After the cursor was moved in Normal or Visual
>                 mode.  Also when the text of the cursor line
>                 has been changed, e.g., with "x", "rx" or "p".
>                 Not triggered when there is typeahead or when
>                 an operator is pending.
>                 For an example see |match-parens|.
>                 **Careful: This is triggered very often, don't
>                 do anything that the user does not expect or
>                 that is slow.**

Knowing that we have an event to drill into should give enough information to get started. If in doubt I'd head to google with that event in hand + `site:github.com`.

(let me know if you'd like a more complete walkthrough of a solution [can make an attempt when I get some coffee in the system])